# Setting an active menu item current URL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add active class to current menu item. So far my HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="navmenu" class="navigation">
<li >
    <a href="#"> Home</a>
</li>
<li class="sub_navmenu">
    <a href="#">About me</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  <ul>
```

It would be nice to have active class on for example on item 1 and parent li element which is sub_navmenu. 
My jQuery is like this:

```
$(function () {
setNavigacija();
   });

  function setNavigacija() {
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
   path = decodeURIComponent(path);

  $("#navmenu li a").each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    }
   });
 }
```

Fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/41uLs8md/12/

Comment: I will use links to redirect to antoher page, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem with your `if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {`

You can try something link this.

```
$(function () {
    setNavigacija();
});

function setNavigacija() {
    var path = window.location.href;
    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);
    $("#navmenu li a").each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (path.indexOf(href) != -1) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
    setNavigacija();
});

function setNavigacija() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);
 //$(".sub_navmenu ul li a").addClass('active');
    $("#navmenu li a").each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
    });
     $(".sub_navmenu ul li").click(function(){
          $(this).find('a').toggleClass('active');
     });
}
```

```css
.navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  
}
.sub_navmenu > ul {
   list-style-type: none;
}
.active {
  
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="navmenu" class="navigation">
    <li >
        <a href="#"> Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub_navmenu">
        <a href="#">About me</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 <ul>
```

Is this is what are you expecting to do?

Comment: Hello thank you for code, something similar, I'm trying to make About me have active class and item 1 if i click on that link if you know what i mean. Also when I click home link it also must have active class.

Comment: Oh! You want to add the active class on `a` when the user clicks. Am I right? I updated answer plz check.

Comment: Now is better, when i click on home link there is no active class on it, in your example above?

Comment: I added the click event for `sub_navmenu`. You can add it for `navmenu` if you want.

Comment: I add it navmenu click event but still home link doesn't have active class?